# Chrome extension: How to reset an optional extension permission when testing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension, and I'm trying to test the user approval/denial of an optional permission.

The problem is that after I click to approve the permission, Chrome does not ask for that permission again. Using [chrome.permissions.remove](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/permissions/#step-5-remove-the-permissions) does not help. It does remove the permission from the list returned by `chrome.permissions.getAll()`, but when the permission is subsequently requested again, it is automatically granted and the user is not prompted to approve it.

It also does not help to remove the unpacked extension and then to load it again. Chrome remembers that the optional permission was approved.

Is there any way to force Chrome to forget the permission, without having to create a fresh Chrome profile for each test? The particular permission in question is `tabGroups`, for which there is no option in the "View web permissions" list that can be opened by right-clicking the extension's page action icon.

Comment: @wOxxOm In Chrome, the `tabGroups` optional permission does need a warning, even if the `tabs` permission is already granted as a non-optional permission. Interestingly, Edge does not need a warning for `tabGroups` if `tabs` is already granted.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome then. It probably conflates the permissions for tabs and tabGroups internally.

Comment: @wOxxOm do you know of a reference that stipulates that `tabGroups` does not need a warning if `tabs` is granted? In Chrome, there are two different warnings displayed if both permissions are requested. `tabs` warns the extenstion can "Read your browsing history", and `tabGroups` warns the extension can "View and manage your tab groups"

Comment: My idea was that it's a bug i.e. a mistake in Chromium.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, I understand that, I was just wondering what made you think that the tabGroups permission would not require a warning. Thanks for your help, btw, you have some great answers on SO.